# How to redefine nautilius unmount to turn off the unmounted hard drive as well?

Tags: nautilus, hard-drive, suspend, unmount

I have just installed an hdd caddy for my second hard drive. I would like nautilus to turn it off when all of its partitions are turned off (to simplify it we can assume that there is only one partition).

The idea is to launch

```
$ sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sdb
```

after all partitions of this drive have been unmounted.

How can I "redefine" nautilius' unmount command to work that way ?